# Viewing the values that make up binned data in the form of factors

Tags: r

So I have two columns of data that I bin and after binning I split the binned data of one column by another and produce a frequency table from that. So with the following example:-

```
column1 <- as.numeric(c("100.01", "100.015", "100.017", "100.071", "100.099", "100.111", "100.153", "100.167"))
column2 <- as.numeric(c("0.89", "0.64", "-0.14", "-0.79", "1", "0.31", "-0.27", "0.45"))
test <- cbind(column1, column2)
bin1 <- seq(100, 100.2, by = 0.05)
bin2 <- seq(-1, 1, by = 0.5)
res <- data.frame(Map(function(x,y) cut(x, breaks=y),
     as.data.frame(test), list(bin1, bin2)))

res1 <- cbind(test, res)
res1
  column1 column2        column1   column2
1 100.010    0.89   (100,100.05]   (0.5,1]
2 100.015    0.64   (100,100.05]   (0.5,1]
3 100.017   -0.14   (100,100.05]  (-0.5,0]
4 100.071   -0.79 (100.05,100.1] (-1,-0.5]
5 100.099    1.00 (100.05,100.1]   (0.5,1]
6 100.111    0.31 (100.1,100.15]   (0,0.5]
7 100.153   -0.27 (100.15,100.2]  (-0.5,0]
8 100.167    0.45 (100.15,100.2]   (0,0.5]
```

I want to split column 2 binned data by column 1 and then from that determine the median of the values that make up the bins for column 1, so it would look something like this:-

```
Freq <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(res1[,4], res1[,3]),table))
Freq
               (-1,-0.5] (-0.5,0] (0,0.5] (0.5,1]
(100,100.05]           0        1       0       2
(100.05,100.1]         1        0       0       1
(100.1,100.15]         0        0       1       0
(100.15,100.2]         0        1       1       0
```

From this I want to be able to look at the values that fall into each pairing, so if I want to look at the values that (100,100.05] and (0.5,1] (the one with two values in it) then I want a way of retrieving the first column values that fell into that given bin and calculating the mean. So with the example above, if I wanted to look at all the values that are within the bin (0.5,1], then I want the output of:-

```
                (0.5,1]
(100,100.05]     100.0125
(100.05,100.1]   100.099
(100.1,100.15]   NA
(100.15,100.2]   NA
```

Thanks

Comment: You can create a "pairing" factor with `pairing<-interaction(res1[,4], res1[,3])`. You can use that as a parameter to `tapply()` to calculate medians. However, i'm still a bit unclear from your description exactly what your desired output is. You can do statements like `res1[res1[,3]=="(100,100.05]" & res1[,4]=="(0.5,1]",]` to subset based on factor/bin levels.

Comment: Basically I want to be able to calculate the median of the values that make up a given pair, using the values from the first column. So with the statement you wrote using `interaction`, I want to do something like that but then look at the values that fall within those pairings and calculate their median. I just tried to use it as a parameter with tapply() but I can't seem to get it to work. I'll also have a look at dcast!

Comment: I've just edited my post with the desired output

Comment: You can get the desired output with `library(reshape2);dcast(res1, column1.1~column2.1, value.var='column1', mean)` Note that the column names in `res1` are duplicated. So, `column1.1` and `column2.1` are 3rd and 4th columns

Comment: Hmmm I seem to be getting the error message `Error in median.default(.value[0], ...) : need numeric data` when I try to perform this

Comment: @user2062207 Please check the class of the `column1` in your dataset.  You were doing `cbind` and I am guessing that the `res1` in your post is a matrix which can hold only a single class.  So, if there is a character column, all the other columns will be coerced to character.

Comment: I think it won't work for the 3rd and 4th columns as they are factors

Comment: ah that works brilliantly! Thank you, can you put it as the answer

Comment: @user2062207  Thanks, I posted that as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
res1 <- data.frame(test, res)
library(reshape2)
res2 <- dcast(res1, column1.1~column2.1, value.var='column1', mean)
res2
#      column1.1 (-1,-0.5] (-0.5,0] (0,0.5]  (0.5,1]
#1   (100,100.05]       NaN  100.017     NaN 100.0125
#2 (100.05,100.1]   100.071      NaN     NaN 100.0990
#3 (100.1,100.15]       NaN      NaN 100.111      NaN
#4 (100.15,100.2]       NaN  100.153 100.167      NaN
```

If you need to get the `mean` of both 'column1' and 'column2', `dcast` from the devel version of `data.table` (i.e. `v1.9.5`) can be used.  It can take multiple `value.vars`.  Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
dcast(setDT(res1), column1.1~column2.1, 
         value.var=c('column1', 'column2'), mean)
```